# Alfa AWUS036nha external USB adapter doesn't work with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, wifi, usb

I am a budding Ubuntu user and unfortunately have been facing "WiFi adapter not found" for ages now on Ubuntu 18.04. Hence based on web research, I found that Atheros AR9271 USB driver works well as an external WiFi adapter.

I have tried everything to get it started. (From rtl88XXXX modprob, make, install to install atheros firmware...you name it!). **Nothing works**! My machine's built in WiFi adapter is the Broadcom one.

Following are some specs for your consideration:

- network

  ```
  description: Network controller
  product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
  vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
  physical id: 0
  bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
  version: 03
  width: 64 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
  configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
  resources: irq:18 memory:c1200000-c1207fff memory:c1000000-c11fffff
  ```
- network

  ```
  description: Ethernet interface
  physical id: 3
  logical name: enp0s20u1u2
  serial: ba:df:bc:e9:8c:44
  capabilities: ethernet physical
  configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005       firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.14 link=yes multicast=yes
  ```
- Result of `lsusb`

  ```
  Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:0812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
  Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
  Bus 001 Device 006: ID 048d:8386 Integrated Technology Express, Inc.
  Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1bcf:2c43 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.
  Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e07a Foxconn / Hon Hai
  Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0cf3:9271 Qualcomm Atheros Communications AR9271 802.11n    
  Bus 001 Device 008: ID 2a70:f00e
  Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:0812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
  Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
  ```

Any help whatsoever is highly appreciated! Thank you in advance!